# cerberus. at least one of two keys should be present is json

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

I'm using [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/) to validate the data posted as JSON to a Flask-based ReST-API. I want at least one of the two fields `freight_id` and `tender_id` to be present.

These mappings would be considered as valid:

```
{"freight_id": 1, "price" : 12000}

{"tender_id": 1, "price": 12000}

{"freight_id": 1, "tender_id" : 2, "price": 12000}
```

While this one would not:

```
{"price": 12000}
```

How can I formulate a schema for such validation with Cerberus?

I almost read all documentation, but did not find any answer. The [`excludes`](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#excludes)-rule doesn't fit my need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using cerberus 1.0, you can implement this using `oneof` rule in its agglutinating form as in this documentation [example](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#of-rules-typesaver). With this, you can validate against different schemas of which exactly one must validate:

The downside is that you may need an additional level on you dict, like `price` below:

First schema, freight and price:

```
>>> schema_1 = {'freight_id': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True},
...             'price': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True}}
```

Second schema, tender and price:

```
>>> schema_2 = {'tender_id': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True},
...             'price': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True}}
```

Third schema, freight, tender and price:

```
>>> schema_3 = {'tender_id': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True},
...             'freight_id': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True},
...             'price': {'type': 'integer', 'required': True}}
```

Putting these together:

```
>>> from cerberus import Validator
>>>
>>> price_validator = Validator(
...     {'price': {'type': 'dict', 
...                'oneof_schema': [schema_1, schema_2, schema_3]}})
```

The results:

```
>>> price_validator.validate({"price": {"freight_id": 1, "price" : 12000}}) 
True
>>> price_validator.validate({"price": {"tender_id": 2, "price" : 12000}})
True
>>> price_validator.validate(
...     {"price": {"freight_id": 1, "tender_id": 2, "price": 1200}}) 
True

>>> price_validator.validate({"price": {"freight_id": 1, "tender_id": 2}}) 
False 
>>> price_validator.validate({"price": {"price" : 12000}})
False
```

Comment: <code>request.json</code> acts as the upper level you told about!. Your solution works for me nicely!

Answer (score 4):

@gcw's solution can be made even shorter:

```
from cerberus import Validator, rules_set_registry

required_integer = {'type': 'integer', 'required': True}

schemas = (
    {'freight_id': required_integer, 'price': required_integer},
    {'tender_id': required_integer, 'price': required_integer},
    {'freight_id': required_integer, 'tender_id': required_integer,
     'price': required_integer},
)
```

As the three schemas are mutually exclusive anyway, there's no need to use the `one_of` rule, simply test whether one matches:

```
validator = Validator()
valid = any(validator(document, schema) for schema in schemas)
```

Comment: Is there maybe a way to perform the same thing with Cerberus < 1.0?

Comment: The trouble with this is that `validator.errors` won't really give an error message that is helpful to the end user. I don't understand why cerberus don't allow a `one_of` for top level elements.